# Ansible/Jinja2 error: no filter named 'map'

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

Running an Ansible playbook on a centos7 server. site.yml includes the following:

```
elastic_cluster_ips: "{{ groups['es_cluster'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | list}}"
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ groups['es_cluster'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | list}}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: template error while templating string: no filter named 'map'. String: {{ groups['es_cluster'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | list}}"}
```

Preliminary searching looked like it might be a jinja2 version issue with earlier versions not having the map filter. I've checked my version though and it seems to be up to date. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Versions:
ansible 2.6.7, 
python 2.6.6,
jinja2 2.10

Thanks!

Comment: Hi acjes, welcome to SO. Does the **target** machine(s) also have a modern python? And can you share with us how you determined that your jinja2 is the correct version?

Comment: Hi @MatthewLDaniel,

Sorry for the delay. The target machines are all running python version 2.7.12.  
And I checked jinja2 version by running 'pip show jinja2' (on the server I'm running the playbook from) and got this output:  
Name: Jinja2 
Version: 2.10
Summary: A small but fast and easy to use stand-alone template engine written in pure python.
Home-page: http://jinja.pocoo.org/
Author: Armin Ronacher
Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages
Requires: MarkupSafe
Required-by:

Comment: I hope you appreciate that 2.7.12 is none of those numbers you posted, and so far all of the python numbers you've posted don't include python3.4, which is where your jinja2 is installed. I'd wager that creating a virtualenv, installing ansible into **that** will work out much better for you than whatever situation you're in right now